# Avoid empty body when filling page using Ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, templates

I'm stuck in a problem on my work. Currently we are using Bootstrap + jQuery and a REST API to fill our pages.

In terms of page loading this is the flow that follows:

- Server receives petition
- Response the template which loads all the assets (CSS and JS)
- The JS file calls the proper REST and fills the body using some divs with ID

The thing is that if I try to fill the body before calling `$(document.ready(function(){`
nothing will be displayed but if I do it afterwards you can see an empty blank page for 1-3 seconds and then suddenly filled by the REST response.

I'd like to know if there is any way (jQuery or external libs are fine as long as it can fix this issue) to fill the body prior to showing the template to the user.

Thanks in advance, if there is more info needed (scripts or w/e) ask and I'll update the post.

Comment: Can you include your current code and a fiddle example - even if its just a watered down version?

Comment: In the `<head>`, initiate the AJAX download before anything else. Once the `document` is ready, [use a promise](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) to add it to the page. That will minimize the delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var res = $.ajax({ ... });
            $(document).ready(function(){
                res.done( function(data){
                    $("body").html(data);
                });    
            });
        <script>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```